# ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, loops

why this code is wrong?

```
for i,j in range(100),range(200,300):
    print i,j
```

when I test this for statement I see this error

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

but when I test

```
for i, j in range(2),range(2):
     print i,j
```

every thing is correct!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`range(2)` gives a list [0, 1]. So, your `i, j` will be fetched from first list and and then from the second list.

So, your loop is similar to: -

```
for i, j in [0, 1], [0, 1]:
    print i, j
```

Prints: -

```
0 1
0 1
```

Now, if you have `range(3)` there, then it will fail, because, `range(3)` gives a 3-element list, which cannot be unpacked in `two loop variables`.

So, you cannot do: -

```
for (i, j) in [[0, 1, 2]]:
    print i, j
```

It will fail, giving you the error that you are getting.

Try using `zip`, to zip your both list into one.: -

```
>>> for (i, j) in (zip(range(2), range(3))):
    print i, j


0 0
1 1
>>>
```

`zip` converts your lists into list of tuples with `2` elements in the above case, as you are zipping 2 lists.

```
>>> zip(range(2), range(3))
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Similarly, if you `zip` three lists, you will get list of 3-elements tuple.

Comment: Worth noting that in Python 3 at least, `range(2)` is not a `list`. -> `>>> type(range(2))` returns `<class 'range'>`

Answer (score 5):

`range(200), range(300)` is too long to look at, but we can understand that case by looking at `range(2), range(3)` instead<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
iterable = (range(2), range(3))
print(iterable)
for i, j in iterable:
     print(repr(i))
```

first prints

```
([0, 1], [0, 1, 2])    #<-- This is what your iterable looks like
0
```

then raises

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

In the first pass through the loop, `i` equals 0 and `j` equals 1.
In the second pass, `i,j` is assigned to `[0,1,2]`. Clearly there are too many values to unpack, hence the exception.

---

Footnote<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
for i, j in range(2), range(3):
```

is equivalent to

```
for i, j in (range(2), range(3)):
```

which is equivalent to

```
iterable = (range(2), range(3))
for i, j in iterable:
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `zip`:

```
for i, j in zip(range(2),range(2)):
     print i,j
```

That's just the Python syntax. If you want to have two loop variables, the iterated object must contain sequences with length of two. Your statement, however, is the same as:

```
i, j = range(100)
```

You're iterating over the sequence `[range(100), range(100)]`. The first iteration returns `range(100)`, and as you can see by the previous example, that obviously fails.

It works with `range(2)` because that returns a sequence with the length of two that your `i,j` statement can be unpacked to.

Comment: This is correct, but could you give an explanation?  It's not immediately clear why this is the case.